# Scope singleton from a library per request

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using a library that requires me to create a client instance before starting a reqeust. But the client instance is a singleton. This client has the login credentials and other information of the current user. The problem is, When I execute multiple reqeusts. those singletons get switched around. Is there a way where I can scope the instance per request.

I can't provide exact code but this is how it goes.

```
Library.ConnectionFactory.CreateInstance(user);
Library.ClientsFactory.DoRequestToXService();
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fit in with your workflow, but maybe you could create a console app which wraps the library, and start it using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class? Then each instance of the console app will have its own instance of the singleton.

Comment: This was something I was thinking about. Wouldn't this create a big overhead?

Comment: I'm not sure; I guess it would depend on how much memory the library consumes?